# How to grep in dplyr with mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like some help understanding what is going on in my `dplyr` pipe and am requesting various solutions to this problem.

### Problem

I have a list of institutes (the formal term for where the authors from papers hail from for a research journal article) and I'd like to extract the main institute name. If it's a university, it will be Univ. of XX and that is the example I'm sticking to here for simplicity.

### Attempted Solution Logic

1. Split the institute name by comma
2. grep for the term "univ" or other list of university-related terms
3. extract the index where there is a hit

### Edge cases / assumptions

- The term I am searching for exists in only one of the splits
- all institutes here are universities (keeping the problem simple here for Stack Overflow)

### Code

```
df %>%
mutate(instGuess = unlist(strsplit(institute, ","))[grep("univ", unlist(strsplit(institute, ",")))][1]) %>%
 head()
```

What I **assume** is happening but is not happening is the logic I wrote above. What I see happening is that within mutate, the first instance of `institute` is being searched for EVERY row in `df` and the exact same "university of new so~" is filling in. I have a general idea for what the mistake is except no idea why it's happening or how to fix it while keeping `dplyr`. If I use an `apply` function I can do this and I'm curious what SO answers there are.

What it Looks Like:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  institute                                                                          instGuess              
  <chr>                                                                              <chr>                  
1 school of computer science and engineering, university of new south wales, sydney~ " university of new so~
2 department computer science, friedrich-alexander-university, erlangen-nuremberg, ~ " university of new so~
3 department of ece, pesit, bangalore, india                                         " university of new so~
4 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queens~ " university of new so~
5 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queens~ " university of new so~
6 dept. of info. syst. and comp. sci., national university of singapore, 10 kent ri~ " university of new so~
```

### Data Used for Example

```
df <- structure(list(institute = c("school of computer science and engineering, university of new south wales, sydney, australia", 
"department computer science, friedrich-alexander-university, erlangen-nuremberg, germany", 
"department of ece, pesit, bangalore, india", "school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queenslandqld, australia", 
"school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queenslandold, australia", 
"dept. of info. syst. and comp. sci., national university of singapore, 10 kent ridge crescent, singapore 119260, singapore"
), instGuess = c(" university of new south wales", " university of new south wales", 
" university of new south wales", " university of new south wales", 
" university of new south wales", " university of new south wales"
)), .Names = c("institute", "instGuess"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: A syntactically simple option is `df %>% separate_rows(institute, sep = ',\\s*') %>% filter(grepl('university', institute))`. It captures duplicates and drops rows without matches, for better or worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @Pdubbs' answer is the first best, where he uses `group_by` to mimic @www's answer that uses `rowwise()`, but the difference (and in my mind clear advantage) is that when there are repeats of `$institute`, there is efficiency gained by only doing this guess once per institute.

This goes one step further and does not re-`strsplit` on each instance. I'll duplicate the first row:

```
df <- df[c(1,1:6),]
```

define a function that does the work, not duplicating `strsplit`:

```
find_univ <- function(x) {
  message('*', appendLF=FALSE)
  y <- strsplit(x[[1]], ',')[[1]]
  y[grep('univ', y)][1]
}
```

(and inserting a `message` call to indicate how many times it is called ... do not include in production), then the sequence:

```
df %>%
  group_by(institute) %>%
  mutate(instGuess = find_univ(institute)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(instGuess) # for display purposes only
# ******  <---- six calls on seven rows, benefit of group_by
# A tibble: 7 × 1
#                           instGuess
#                               <chr>
# 1     university of new south wales
# 2     university of new south wales
# 3    friedrich-alexander-university
# 4                              <NA>
# 5       university of queenslandqld
# 6       university of queenslandold
# 7  national university of singapore
```

I don't know if this de-duplication of `strsplit` is impactful, though it is only beneficial if you have a large amount of data. Otherwise, it's just an OCD-level of efficiency without ["premature optimization"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/147602).

Comment: I agree. `group_by` is better than `rowwise` in this case.

Comment: I've used `rowwise` many times, and often regret it in the end due to performance. I still use it at times when it is unavoidable, just like I have `do({...})` blocks that are grossly inefficient but I haven't found a clean way around them.

Comment: Yes, I agree. `rowwise` and `do` is easy to use, but there is often a better way. Thanks for sharing your solution.

Comment: This is a nice addition to @Pdubb's first response, and helps me understand the optimization that is possible (even if it falls in the 97% category, good post)

Answer (score 5):

You need to include a `group_by` for your syntax to work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(institute) %>%
  mutate(instGuess = unlist(strsplit(institute, ","))[grep("univ", unlist(strsplit(institute, ",")))][1])
```

Produces:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   institute [6]
institute                                                                  instGuess              
<chr>                                                                      <chr>                  
  1 school of computer science and engineering, university of new south wales… " university of new so…
2 department computer science, friedrich-alexander-university, erlangen-nur… " friedrich-alexander-…
3 department of ece, pesit, bangalore, india                                 NA                     
4 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university o… " university of queens…
5 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university o… " university of queens…
6 dept. of info. syst. and comp. sci., national university of singapore, 10… " national university …
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub`

```
a=df %>%
     group_by(institute)%>%
     mutate(Instname=sub("(.*,\\s|)(.*unive.*?)(,|$).*|.*","\\2",institute))
> a
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   institute [6]
  institute                                                                                           Instname                   
  <chr>                                                                                               <chr>                      
1 school of computer science and engineering, university of new south wales, sydney, australia        university of new south wa~
2 department computer science, friedrich-alexander-university, erlangen-nuremberg, germany            friedrich-alexander-univer~
3 department of ece, pesit, bangalore, india                                                          ""                         
4 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queenslandqld, australia university of queenslandqld
5 school of information technology and electrical engineering, university of queenslandold, australia university of queenslandold
6 dept. of info. syst. and comp. sci., national university of singapore, 10 kent ridge crescent, sin~ national university of sin~
> a$Instname
[1] "university of new south wales"    "friedrich-alexander-university"   ""                                
[4] "university of queenslandqld"      "university of queenslandold"      "national university of singapore"
```

Comment: This will not work if the `univ` portion is the first or last among the comma-separated strings. Would it be better to use `sub("(^.*,|^)([^,]*univ[^,]*),?.*$|^.*$", "\\2", institute[1])`?

Comment: look at the second row.. `university` is last, but it was captured!!! so I do not understand what youmean

Comment: Try with `"university of new south wales, sydney, australia"` or `"school of computer science and engineering, university of new south wales"` to see what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you mean.. If the whole sentence started with University.. I understand.. or ends with University... okay

Comment: I admit that they are not included in the OP and might be mal-formed in the big picture, but then again data that has been scraped gathered by something else is rarely perfect.

Comment: Will just do a quick fix

Comment: Your use of `sub` is faster than my `find_univ` by about 30% (given the small data here), but with larger data (~500K rows) it becomes much less pronounced (but is still a little faster).

Comment: You can use `gsub ` with `perl=TRUE` to improve on the speed. Using `perl=T` will significantly improve the speed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like only the first element is used. We can use `rowwise` to group each row and make sure the operation is row specific.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(instGuess = unlist(strsplit(institute, ","))[grep("univ", unlist(strsplit(institute, ",")))][1]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  head()
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
# institute                                                              instGuess             
#   <chr>                                                                  <chr>                 
# 1 school of computer science and engineering, university of new south w~ " university of new s~
# 2 department computer science, friedrich-alexander-university, erlangen~ " friedrich-alexander~
# 3 department of ece, pesit, bangalore, india                             NA                    
# 4 school of information technology and electrical engineering, universi~ " university of queen~
# 5 school of information technology and electrical engineering, universi~ " university of queen~
# 6 dept. of info. syst. and comp. sci., national university of singapore~ " national university~
```